# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop for ARM64: Unable to install gobjc++

Tags: software-installation

I'm unable to install gobjc++ on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop (fully patched) for ARM64:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gobjc++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gobjc++ : Depends: gobjc++-9 (>= 9.3.0-3~) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: gobjc (>= 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: "focal-updates **universe**" : The gobjc++-9 version is `9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/gobjc++-9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: thank you: You're suggesting to add the universe-repository? sudo add-apt-repository universe It is already enabled (by default): 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources. Any other idea? THANKS!

Comment: Could you try running `sudo apt update` and try again?